# Rscript: how is $ interpreted in strings passed as inline code

Tags: r, special-characters, rscript

Does anyone know how $ is interpreted within an inline call to rscript?

In the example below, I am trying to get z to be the "a" element within the x list. However, z=x$a gives me x instead of the element of the list.

```
> Rscript -e "x = list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6)); z = x$a; print(z); print(\"z$a\")"
$a
[1] 1 2 3

$b
[1] 4 5 6

[1] "z"
```

Notice that even in the print statement, the $ causes somewhat obscure behavior. I would have expected this to print z$a, but it prints z instead.

Two questions:

1. How exactly is "$" interpreted within a string used as inline
   code to Rscript?
2. How can I refer to an element in a list within
   inline code passed to rscript?

Comment: This likely has more to do with your shell than Rscript. What shell are you running? Sounds like the value is being interpreted before Rscript even sees it.

Comment: @MrFlick: I am using bash

Comment: Then this is a problem with bash doing variable substitution on your string. I don't use bash myself but i think you can prevent expansion with single quotes: `Rscript -e 'x = list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6)); z = x$a; print(z); print ("z$a")'`

Comment: @MrFlick: Thanks. Do I understand it correctly that bash is substituting $a by the value of the shell variable a, which, since it is not defined, is defaulted to $a=""?

Comment: Yes, that's consistent with your results. (I don't use bash as my primary shell so i'm not as familiar with what's returned for undefined variables)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer you second question, you could do `x[['a']]`

Comment: Thanks for the alternative: much cleaner than using \$ and, likely, less shell specific.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that using \$ instead of $ in the inline code does the trick.

```
>/lrlhps/apps/R/R-3.1.1/bin/Rscript -e "x = list(a=c(1,2,3), b=c(4,5,6)); z = x\$a; print(z); print(\"z\$a\")"
[1] 1 2 3
[1] "z$a"
```

Still, does anyone what "$" does?